# How can I redirect a page that does not exist anymore?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

We recently moved our website to WordPress. The old site was built in plain old html. We are no longer hosting the pages ending in .htm but there are still links to them that exist on the web and it's returning 404 errors. I want to direct the old pages that ended in .htm to the new page that is now living in WordPress. I have tried a handful of SEO redirect plugins in WordPress which none have seemed to work. How would I go about doing this if the page no longer exists on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).